# Fourier transform in three dimensions getting out of hand

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

I have the following integral I wish to compute, it transforms a quantum position wave function into momentum space:

$$\phi(\mathbf p)=\int\frac{\mathrm d^3r}{(2\pi\hbar)^{3/2}}e^{-i\mathbf{p\cdot r}}\psi(\mathbf r)$$
Where $\psi(\mathbf r)=e^{-|\mathbf r|/a}/\sqrt{\pi a^3}$, the wave equation for the ground state of hydrogen.

So I thought about converting it to polar coordinates first then evaluate the integrals, but it turned out to be unexpectedly complicated.

Below is my attempt (note, since this is physics related, $\theta$ is swapped with $\varphi$ in polar coordinates):

---

We first rewrite the integral in polar coordinates:
$$\phi(r_p, \varphi_p, \theta_p)=\frac{1}{(2a\hbar)^{3/2}\pi^2}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-i\mathbf{p\cdot x}/h-r_x/a}\mathrm d r_x\mathrm d\varphi_x \mathrm d\theta_x$$

Where the dot product in spherical coordinates is:
$$\mathbf{p\cdot x}=r_xr_p[\sin\theta_p\sin\theta_x\cos(\varphi_p-\varphi_x)+\cos\theta_p\cos\theta_x]$$

Substitute and integrate, we get:
\begin{align*}\phi(r_p, \varphi_p, \theta_p)&=\frac{1}{(2a\hbar)^{3/2}\pi^2ir_p}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{\mathrm d\theta_x \mathrm d\varphi_x}{\sin\theta_p\sin\theta_x\cos(\varphi_p-\varphi_x)+\cos\theta_p\cos\theta_x}\\
\textrm{Now let: } a &=\sin\theta_p\cos(\varphi_p-\varphi_x)\\
b &=\cos\theta_p \\
\phi&=\frac{1}{(2a\hbar)^{3/2}\pi^2ir_p}\int_0^\pi \frac{\ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a)-\ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\mathrm d\varphi_x\\
\end{align*}

---

The second integral is evaluated from wolfram alpha. From here I'm quite stuck. The final integral looks rather hopeless. Is there any tricks to Fourier transforms in space or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Edit: I think I accidentally substituted $2\pi$ instead of $\pi$, but the correct version is even more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symmetry is your friend.  Since $\psi$ is radially symmetric, so is $\phi$.
So wlog we can assume ${\bf p} = p \bf k$, and ${\bf p} . {\bf r} = p r \cos(\theta)$. Then

$$\eqalign{\phi(p {\bf k}) &= \dfrac{1}{(2 a \hbar)^{3/2} \pi^2} \int_0^{2\pi} d\varphi  \int_{0}^\infty r^2 \; dr \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(\theta)\; d\theta\; e^{ip r \cos(\theta)} e^{-r/a}\cr &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2} (a \hbar)^{3/2} \pi}
\int_0^\infty r^2\; dr \dfrac{2 \sin(pr)}{pr} e^{-r/a}\cr
&= \dfrac{4 a^{3/2}
}{\sqrt{2} \hbar^{3/2} \pi (a^2 p^2 + 1)^2}}$$

Comment: That makes sense! Just a small followup - if we assume $\mathbf p=p\mathbf r$ (I assume here that k is r), then why is there still a factor of cosine in the dot product?

Comment: No, I'm **not** assuming ${\bf p} = p \bf r$.  $\bf k$ is the unit vector $ (0,0,1)$ in the $z$ direction.

Comment: But if $\phi$ is radially symmetric, why do we assume it points along the $z$ direction?

Comment: It doesn't "point" anywhere: it's not a vector, it's a function.  Its value at $(0,0,r)$ is the same as its value anywhere else on the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$.

Comment: Right, so its value should represent magnitude in the radial direction? In that case what is the meaning of the dot product? Is the cosine angle the angle between the two radial directions (what does that even look like, when they aren't supposed to be in any specific direction?)